# Remove specific instance when serializing multiple objects (many=True) and one of them has an error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a serializer similar to this:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attr3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelExample
        fields = ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]

    def get_atrr3(self, instance):
        try:
            # Do something
        except Exception:
            raise
```

I'm a serializing a list of objects.

```
ExampleSerializer(object_list, many=True).data
```

**Is there a way to exclude instances raising errors when serializing**.. so I still get the rest of the correct object in the list serialized anyways?

Btw, **I can't pre-filter the object_list** in order to exclude the problematic items.

Comment: I think that out-of-the-box `many=True` will make this hard to do. I'm unsure how you're returning the payload as as response here, but if possible you could compose your list of serialized entities by hand (passing over errors), and return that. Doing this in a ViewSet however would likely result in buggy behavior when it comes to pagination. TBH this idea smells a bit- are you truly sure you can't pre-filter your object list?