# How to Serialize only valid objects in Django Rest Framework with many=True?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am asking this question after making a search on the Internet and found nothing of use. (Except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387878/remove-specific-instance-when-serializing-multiple-objects-many-true-and-one-o) question, which was not answered)

I have the following serializer

```py
class StudentSerializer(Serializer):
        name = CharField()
        age= IntegerField(min_value=0)
        last_name = CharField(required=False)
        
        def  validate(self, attrs):
            return attrs
```

And following data, to be serialized:

```
data = [
   {
      "name":"Burakhan",
      "age":27,
      "last_name":"Aksoy"
   },
   {
      "name":"Mehmet",
      "age":27,
      "last_name":"Randomname"
   },
   {
      "name":"Cevdet",
      "age":28
   },
   {
      "name":"Ahmet",
      "age":-2, # This is invalid
      "last_name":"Yilmaz"
   }
]
```

When I want to serialize this as follows, `serialized.validated_data` returns an empty List even though only a single object is not valid.

```py
serialized = StudentSerializer(data=data, many=True)
serialized.is_valid()
>>> False
serialized.errors
>>>[{}, {}, {}, {'age': [ErrorDetail(string='Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.', code='min_value')]}

serialized.validated_data
>>> []
```

My question is, how can I have a serializer so that only valid ones are serialized and invalids are discarded?

Thank you

Comment: You may not like it, but this is expected behavior. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6883#issuecomment-523994008. You can make workaround by validating data before passing it to serializer

Comment: I think this would not be good behavior. Usually this means the request will return a 400-499 status code, which normally means that the request did not have any effect. Doing this partially looks like a bad idea.